# Android: Is the permission GET_PACKAGE_SIZE useful

Tags: android, android-permissions, deprecated

Knowing that the method `getPackageSizeInfoAsUser(String packageName, @UserIdInt int userId,IPackageStatsObserver observer);` is deprecated, is the permission `GET_PACKAGE_SIZE` still useful or it is also deprecated in Pie?

Comment: Document says it's not deprected https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#GET_PACKAGE_SIZE

Comment: Ok but when could it be useful? I dont see any code in the Android SDK code that checks/enforces the permission.